# Making fetch API work with CORS after OPTIONS response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cors, fetch-api

I are trying to fetch data from our API. The API has enabled CORS support and returns the below response to the OPTIONS request:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

The API doesn't allow `'Content-type'` anything other than `'application/json'`.

Using this limitation, I am trying to use the `fetch` method of React-Native to get the data.

**Method 1 (no-cors):**

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
       'content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

With this method, the browser automatically sends the content-type as 'text/plain'. I assume this is because CORS allow just one of the three headers by default. However, since the server doesn't support this content-type, it returns an error back for unsupported content type.

**Method 2 (with cors or with nothing):**

```
{ 
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "cors", // or without this line
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
}   
...   
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

In this scenario, using Chrome's F12 network tool, I can see the server returning data : the first request to the server is a `fetch` for `OPTIONS`. To this, the server replies back with an empty object along with the above headers set. The next call is the actual POST API call, to which the server responds back with a proper JSON response containing some data. However, the response which is getting on the console via my code is `{}`. I assume this is because the react's `fetch` API is returning back the response of the `OPTIONS` call instead of the actual `POST` call.

Is there any way to ignore the response of the OPTIONS request and get the `then` method to process the response of the subsequent request?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The immediate problem you’re hitting is, your code as currently written expects the response to be JSON but the response is actually a Promise that you need to handle  to get the JSON.

So you need to instead do something like this:

```
fetch("https://example.com")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsondata => console.log(jsondata))
```