# CORS error when using fetch with Content-Type

Tags: javascript, wcf, iis, cors, fetch

i'm trying to send a POST request to a REST web service from a different domain in FireFox. i'm using the JavaScript "fetch" function for this. i'm hosting the REST web service in IIS. it works fine before i add a "Content-Type" header in JavaScript.

**CORS errors in the FireFox console**

note that if i enable XHR in the console, then i can see that using fetch with the "Content-Type" results in an OPTIONS request. but, not using the "Content-Type" results in a POST request. so fetch is triggering a preflight request as the documentation says. these are the errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/Service.svc/Request. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/Service.svc/Request. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

**JavaScript with CORS error**

```
var body = '{ID:2, Name:"test reqx"}';
var url = "http://example.com/Service.svc/Request";
var init = {credentials:"include", method:"POST", headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}, body:body};
fetch(url,init)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

**JavaScript without CORS error, but also no Content-Type**

```
var body = '{ID:2, Name:"test reqx"}';
var url = "http://example.com/Service.svc/Request";
var init = {credentials:"include", method:"POST", headers:{"Accept":"application/json"}, body:body};
fetch(url,init)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

i'm using 'credentials:"include"' because the REST web service is configured with Basic Authentication.

**REST web service web.config (note the different domain)**

i've added some CORS configurations, to make other requests work cross domain in FireFox. but, i can't find the right configuration to allow Content-Type:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example.net" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,POST"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      ...
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

the REST web service does not work without the "Content-Type" header "application/json". how can i resolve these errors?

**Side note**

using HTTP instead of HTTPS, makes the examples easier (because no certificates needed), but it also sends the credentials for Basic Authentication in plain text

Comment: check this if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759938/making-fetch-api-work-with-cors-after-options-response

Comment: try adding a CORS plugin to chrome and check if it returns a response then you might need to do some header value changes, else code changes

Comment: @Nishant which plugin? if what returns response? the web service responds when not using the Content-Type header

Comment: try this chrome extension, and check if you get the response with content-type. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en#:~:text=Allow%20CORS%3A%20Access%2DControl%2DAllow%2DOrigin%20lets%20you,default%20(in%20JavaScript%20APIs).

Comment: @Nishant that isn't helpful to users of the OPs application.

Comment: @symbiont i see you using wcf - have you configured it to respond to the OPTIONS request? the custom headers stuff is insufficient if that returns an error response code.

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah. it's a wcf service. i haven't changed anything except the customHeaders. the OPTIONS request is getting a 401 Unauthorized response. where would i configure the OPTIONS response?

Comment: @symbiont https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/how-to-add-cross-domain-support-to-wcf-service

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for the suggestion. i will have to try that out

Comment: Have you fixed it by setting response for OPTIONS?

Comment: @JokiesDing will hopefully get the chance to try it today. i will update this question when i know

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks! that led to the solution

Comment: @JokiesDing yes it's fixed now. i put the details in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selected answer, in the question referred to by Daniel A. White, was the solution although slightly modified. [How to add cross domain support to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/how-to-add-cross-domain-support-to-wcf-service).

**Side note**

i noticed different responses to the OPTIONS call when it's not yet fixed:

- 405 Method Not Allowed: with Anonymous Authentication in IIS
- 401 Unauthorized: with Basic Authentication in IIS
  but the CORS errors are the same in both cases as Daniel pointed out

this is how i modified the WCF REST Web Service and got rid of the CORS errors:

**Global.asax.cs**

i also added the Global.asax.cs file to the web service. but i did not add any "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" in there, as it seems to overrule the web.config. so decided to shave it down to the bare minimum:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent 401 unauthorized response to CORS preflight check
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

**Web.config**

i shaved this down to the bare minimum as well (**make sure you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"**)

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    ...
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example.net" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```